# Google drive whats the limit to indexing large files?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm using the google drive api to store and retrieve pdf files. I would like to query these files using the search parameters.

But before I start implementing this. I would like to know how google handles the indexing of large pdf files. (600+pages 25Mb+)  I would like to know for text based pdf's.(they don't need ocr)

I've tried some searches on the drive website and it doesn't always work.

I would like to know if the are any limitations and what they are.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176692&topic=2375187&ctx=topic) for PDFs with OCR:

The maximum size for images (.jpg, .gif, .png) and PDF files (.pdf) is 2 MB. For PDF files, we only look at the first 10 pages when searching for text to extract.

And [this page](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2423485) for PDFs with text:

You can search for text in PDF and image files by:

- Typing a query in the search box in Google Drive on the web.
- Opening the Google Drive viewer and using the search box in the upper right.

In theory you should be able to search the first 100 pages of any text documents or text-based PDFs that you've uploaded. You'll also be able to search for text found on the first ten pages of any image PDFs on your Drive.

Comment: This is only for pdf's with ocr. I would like to know for text based pdf's.

Comment: Good point, I think I've found the answer to that one as well now in my updated answer.

Comment: I think those 100 pages is only for the pdf viewer search.

Comment: The information I've found so far (discussions in Google Groups support forums) seems to suggest that the view is limited to 25 MB PDF files (larger files just present a download button)

Comment: It only searches the first 100 pages if you use the viewer I've tested it. When you search the entire drive it doesn't search in 100 pages. I've tested it and found that it only does like 40-50 pages, very random. The pdf's do contain images so I think there's a memory limit on indexing.